# MySQL trigger for insert SQL Server table data in to my SQL table in real time

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

i want write trigger for getting read the record in real time update MS sql data in to the my sql data table every 5 min.(get the unread data an update in mysql table).what is best way to do it?
**I already using method**

```
<?php 
    $serverName = "XXXXXXXXX"; //serverName\instanceName, portNumber (default is 1433)
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"XXXXXX", "UID"=>"XXXXX", "PWD"=>"XXXXXX");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
    $conn_insert = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","XXXXX");
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
    //$currentMonth= date('Y-m');

    $query = "SELECT [EnrolledID]
              , [Date], [Time]
             FROM dbo.UVW_RawAttencance_UNIKEL 
             WHERE [Date] >= '20190901' and [Date] < '21000101'
             ORDER BY [Date] DESC, [Time] DESC;";

    $result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$query,array(), array( "Scrollable" => 'static' ));
    $count01 = sqlsrv_num_rows($result).'<br>';

    $query = "SELECT * FROM attendancedata ORDER BY Date,Time";
    $result02 = mysqli_query($conn_insert, $query);
    $count02 = mysqli_num_rows($result02);

    $max= (int)$count01-(int)$count02;

    if ($count01 == $count02) 
    {

       header("location:attendance.php?state=Success&details=month procees done succesfully");
    }
    else
    {
       if ($count01 > $count02) {

            $query = "SELECT [EnrolledID]
                     , [Date], [Time]
                      FROM dbo.UVW_RawAttencance_UNIKEL 
                      WHERE [Date] >= '20190901' and [Date] < '21000101'
                      ORDER BY Date DESC,Time DESC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT {$max} ROWS ONLY";
            $result03 = sqlsrv_query($conn,$query);
          if ($result03 == FALSE){
           die(FormatErrors(sqlsrv_errors()));
           }
           else{

          while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result03, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))  
           { 

                $emp_no = $row['EnrolledID'];
                $date  = date_format($row['Date'], 'Y-m-d');
                $time = date_format($row['Time'], 'H:i:s');

           $stmt = $conn_insert->prepare('INSERT INTO attendancedata (EnrolledID,Date,Time) VALUES (?,?,?)');
           // I insert as string as was in original question (table metadata was not given...)
           $stmt->bind_param('sss', $emp_no, $date, $time ); // 's' specifies the variable type => 'string'
           $stmt->execute();
           }
           header("location:attendance.php?state=Success&details=month procees done succesfully");
         }  
       }
    }   
?>
```

this working but it have some problem .some data missing in some case?

Comment: `some data missing in some case?` it is hard to understand. Please provide more details.

Comment: missing mean when run the application ms sql database some data not coming to the mysql table .some data double type in the mysql data table

Comment: Why is this post tagged as both `mysql` and `sql-server`?

Comment: Because I used both server